# Reflection - Access custom attributes by name

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to see if a given method is decorated with an attribute, (the attribute in question is `NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute`) but I need to be able to check for the attribute regardless of what version the attribute is. Currently, I have `nunit.framework.dll` version 2.6.2 in the project using reflection, and version 2.6.0 of the dll in the test. The reflection is not finding the attribute.

Is there some way to do

```
bool isTest = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TestAttribute), true).Length > 0;
```

without having access to the correct version of the `TestAttribute` dll?

where method is of type `MethodInfo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all attributes and filter by name:

```
method.GetCustomAttributes(true)
      .Where(a => a.GetType().FullName == "NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute");
```